# Insert line break after each tr tag row

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a line break after each `tr` tag so there a gap between the next row of data. I have included what I thought should work but alas, no luck. Basically, if there are 10 rows of data separate each `tr` with a new line.

I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. many thanks

**UPDATE**: Screen grab to show exactly how I want the row spacing to appear. Notice the spacing at the bottm of each row.

[image]

```css
table tr {
   /*  background: #f8f8f8;*/
   /*border: 1px solid #ddd;*/
}
table th, table td {
   text-align: left;
}
table th {
   font-size: .85em;
   letter-spacing: .1em;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   table {
      border: 1px solid #eee;
      border-radius: 5px !important;
   }
   table thead {
      border: none;
      clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
      height: 1px;
      margin: -1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 1px;
   }
   table tr {
      /*    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;*/
      display: block;
      /*          margin-bottom: .625em;*/
   }
   table td {
      /*    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;*/
      display: block;
      font-size: .85em;
      text-align: left;
      /*          margin-bottom: .625em;*/
   }
   table td:before {
      content: attr(data-label);
      float: left;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
   }
   table td:last-child {
      /*          border-bottom: 0;*/
      content: "" !important;
      white-space: pre !important;
   }
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <caption>
            <h3>Caption</h3>
          </caption>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Amount</th>
              <th scope="col">Period</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td data-label="Due Date" scope="row">04/01/2016</td>
              <td data-label="Amount">$1,190</td>
              <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td data-label="Due Date" scope="row">03/01/2016</td>
              <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
              <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td data-label="Due Date" scope="row">03/01/2016</td>
              <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
              <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td data-label="Due Date" scope="row">02/01/2016</td>
              <td data-label="Amount">$842</td>
              <td data-label="Period">01/01/2016 - 01/31/2016</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: Is this topic always open?

Answer (score 1):

I played a little with your code and ended up with this:
(I only added `margin-bottom: 3em;` in `table tr td:last-child { … }`)
Feel free to comment if you want some modification.

```css
table th,
table td {
  text-align: left;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
  }
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  table tr {
    display: block;
  }
  table td {
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    text-align: left;
  }
  table td:before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  table tr td:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    content: "" !important;
    white-space: pre !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <caption>
      <h3>Caption</h3>
    </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
        <th scope="col">Period</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Due Date" scope="row">04/01/2016</td>
        <td data-label="Amount">$1,190</td>
        <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Due Date" scope="row">03/01/2016</td>
        <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
        <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Due Date" scope="row">03/01/2016</td>
        <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
        <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Due Date" scope="row">02/01/2016</td>
        <td data-label="Amount">$842</td>
        <td data-label="Period">01/01/2016 - 01/31/2016</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you just want an empty line between each row. If that's the case then you'd want to target the **td** tag not the **tr** tag. You would add `padding-bottom: 1em;` to all rows and specify that the last row has `padding-bottom: 0;`. Try this solution:

```css
table th, table td {
   text-align: left;
}
table th {
   font-size: .85em;
   letter-spacing: .1em;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   table {
      border: 1px solid #eee;
      border-radius: 5px !important;
   }
   table thead {
      border: none;
      clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
      height: 1px;
      margin: -1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 1px;
   }
   table tr {
      display: block;
   }
   table td {
      display: block;
      font-size: .85em;
      text-align: left;
      padding-bottom: 1em;
   }
   table td:before {
      content: attr(data-label);
      float: left;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
   }
   table td:last-child {
      content: "" !important;
      white-space: pre !important;
   }
   
   table tr:last-child td:last-child{
       padding-bottom: 0;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <caption>
      <h3>Caption</h3>
    </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
        <th scope="col">Period</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Due Date" scope="row">04/01/2016</td>
        <td data-label="Amount">$1,190</td>
        <br/>
        <td data-label="Period">03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Due Date" scope="row">03/01/2016</td>
        <td data-label="Amount">$2,443</td>
        <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Due Date" scope="row">03/01/2016</td>
        <td data-label="Amount">$1,181</td>
        <td data-label="Period">02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Due Date" scope="row">02/01/2016</td>
        <td data-label="Amount">$842</td>
        <td data-label="Period">01/01/2016 - 01/31/2016</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you see the space when running the snippet?… I'm asking because I don't.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference Oliver. I have attached a screenshot to show exactly what I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Olivier answer is good, but I think border-spacing is more appropriate here. Padding adds blank space INTO the cells which might have unwanted visual consequences (e.g. when border is displayed).
From what you asked, you probably want the empty space BETWEEN the cells. I would recommend something like this

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 10px; // or 0.85em but i would recommend using pixels here
}
```

The 0 is for horizontal spacing (which you don't want), 10px is for vertical spacing (thats the space between rows).